# Separate integers starting with specific number in c#

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I wanted to write a program which separates the integers from a long paragraphs. I wrote this code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace hhhhh
{

    public class Program 
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string roll;
            roll = Console.ReadLine();
            
            string var = roll;
                                    
            string mynumber = Regex.Replace(var, @"D", "");
            
            Console.WriteLine("Roll Numbers: " + mynumber);
            
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine but the problem is it puts all the numbers from the paragraph together. Like, if i paste this as the `string` **roll**:

> JAKARIA MAHMUD 10:41 AM
> 4005
> TAHAMEED KARIM 10:41 AM
> 4085
> SHAHRIA ILTIMAS 10:41 AM
> 4007
> SAKER MUNSHI 10:41 AM
> 4038

The output shows like this:

> Roll Numbers:
> 10414005104140851041400710414038

But i want the program to separate the integers starting with 4 only and  they should not be together but separate numbers. Like this:

> Roll Numbers:
> 4005, 4085, 4007, 4038

How can i do that? It's for my college's attendance report.

Comment: The code you've shown just removes the character "D" from the string. It doesn't do anything with digits. As a side-note, I'd strongly recommend against using `var` as a variable name, given that it's a contextual keyword in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Regex` *matching* and *Linq* combination:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

public static void Main() {
  string roll = Console.ReadLine();

  string result = string.Join(", ", Regex
    .Matches(roll, "[0-9]{4,}")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value));

  Console.WriteLine("Roll Numbers: " + result);
}
```

I've used `[0-9]{4,}` pattern which matches integers of `4` or more digits only (in order to get rid of `10`, `41` within `10:41` fragment)

Comment: will you kindly say me how the whole code should look like? or Where to place the code that you just gave here? I'm a beginner in C#.

Comment: @Acp Siam: I've edited the answer - now it's entire `Main` method implementation

Answer (score 1):

Use Matches :

```
           string pattern = @"\d+";
            string input = "JAKARIA MAHMUD 10:41 AM 4005 TAHAMEED KARIM 10:41 AM 4085 SHAHRIA ILTIMAS 10:41 AM 4007 SAKER MUNSHI 10:41 AM 4038";

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
            var results = string.Join(",", matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value));
```

Comment: I doubt in `"\d+"` pattern: please, note `10:41 AM` fragment in the example; both `10` and `41` should not be matched

Comment: @DmitryBychenko :  You could use "4\d+"  The op said starting with "4" and did not specifically say to ignore the 41.